# jQuery .siblings() is selecting different parents sibling

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to select a single sibling of a label element, but it's selecting different parents sibling.

Here is my code:

```js
$('.wpas-checkbox-container label').on('click', function() {
  var $$ = $(this);
  if (!$$.is('.checked')) {
    $$.addClass('checked');
    $$.siblings('input.wpas-checkbox').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $$.removeClass('checked');
    $$.siblings('input.wpas-checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```css
.checked {
  border: solid 2px red
}

.wp-advanced-search .wpas-checkbox {
 /*  height: 0;
  width: 0; */
}
.js-wpas-basic-multiple {
    display: inline-grid;
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="wp-advanced-search" name="wp-advanced-search" class="wp-advanced-search wpas-debug-enabled" method="GET" action="/programming/">
  <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkboxes wpas-checkboxes field-container js-wpas-basic-multiple target-areas">
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox--container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="adductors">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-"> Adductors</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-1-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-1" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="anklesfeet">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-1"> Ankles/Feet</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-2-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-2" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="calves">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-2"> Calves</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-3-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-3" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="diaphragm">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-3"> Diaphragm</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-4-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-4" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="forearms">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-4"> Forearms</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-5-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-5" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="hamstrings">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-5"> Hamstrings</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-6-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-6" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="hip-flexors">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-6"> Hip flexors</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-7-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-7" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="hips">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-7"> Hips</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-8-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-8" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="knees">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-8"> Knees</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-9-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-9" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="lats">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-9"> Lats</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-10-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-10" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="neck">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-10"> Neck</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-11-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-11" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="t-spine">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-11"> T-spine</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-12-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-12" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="target-areas">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-12"> Target Areas</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-13-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-13" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="traps">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-13"> Traps</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-14-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-14" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="triceps">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-14"> Triceps</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-15-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-15" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="upper-body">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-15"> Upper body</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-16-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-16" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="wristshands">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-16"> Wrists/Hands</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkboxes wpas-checkboxes field-container js-wpas-basic-multiple movements">
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox--container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="bench-press">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-"> Bench press</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-1-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-1" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="clean">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-1"> Clean</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-2-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-2" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="front-squat">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-2"> Front Squat</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-3-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-3" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="handstand">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-3"> Handstand</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-4-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-4" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="handstand-push-ups">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-4"> Handstand push-ups</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-5-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-5" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="movements">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-5"> Movements</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-6-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-6" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="over-head">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-6"> Over head</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-7-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-7" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="overhead-squat">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-7"> Overhead Squat</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-8-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-8" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="throwing">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-8"> Throwing</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-9-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-9" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="thrusters">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-9"> Thrusters</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkboxes wpas-checkboxes field-container js-wpas-basic-multiple equipments">
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox--container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="barbell">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-"> Barbell</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-1-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-1" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="box">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-1"> Box</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-2-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-2" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="dumbbell">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-2"> Dumbbell</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-3-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-3" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="equipment">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-3"> Equipment</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-4-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-4" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="kettle-bell">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-4"> Kettle bell</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-5-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-5" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="long-bands">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-5"> Long bands</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-6-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-6" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="short-bands">
      <label for="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-6"> Short bands</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="Date Added">
  <div class="label-container">
    <label for="order">Sort By</label>
  </div>
  <select id="order" name="order" class="wpas-select orderbyselector">
    <option value="ASC">Oldest First</option>
    <option value="DESC" selected="selected">Newest First</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" class="wpas-submit button" value="Apply Filters">
  <button class="wpas-clear button">Clear Filters</button>
  <input type="hidden" id="wpas-id" name="wpas_id" value="programming-category-filter">
  <input type="hidden" name="wpas_submit" value="1">
</form>
```

Try to click on any element on the second column.

Comment: Unrelated, but I would advise against using `$$`. It's webkit's "alias" for `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: I have tried using different variable, same result.

Comment: Hence I've started the comment with "Unrelated". It's just a recommendation to practice better naming so you do not override vendor globals.

Comment: Thanks for the note.

Comment: sure seems like a lot of extra work adding all those unique incremented classes ... that probably don't get used for anything important (if at all)

Comment: They are generated by a WP plugin: WPAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's need to be unique, but you're using the same IDs for the checkboxes in each DIV. In my code below, I've changed the IDs of the checkboxes to have a different prefix in each DIV.

Also, `$$.is(':checked')` doesn't work on a label, that property belongs to the associated checkbox. But you don't need to check the checkbox in your code, that happens automatically because you have the `for` attribute in the label. When the code checks the checkbox, it then gets unchecked when the click event goes to the checkbox.

Note that putting the event handler on the label means you only get the highlighting when the user clicks on the label, not when they click on the checkbox itself. You can solve that by either putting the event handler on the checkbox and then adding the class to the `label` sibling, or by wrapping the label around the checkbox instead of making them siblings.

```js
$('.wpas-checkbox-container label').on('click', function() {
  var $$ = $(this);
  if (!$$.siblings('input.wpas-checkbox').is(':checked')) {
    $$.addClass('checked');
  } else {
    $$.removeClass('checked');
  }
});
```

```css
.checked {
  border: solid 2px red
}

.wp-advanced-search .wpas-checkbox {
 /*  height: 0;
  width: 0; */
}
.js-wpas-basic-multiple {
    display: inline-grid;
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="wp-advanced-search" name="wp-advanced-search" class="wp-advanced-search wpas-debug-enabled" method="GET" action="/programming/">
  <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkboxes wpas-checkboxes field-container js-wpas-basic-multiple target-areas">
    <div class="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox--container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="adductors">
      <label for="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-"> Adductors</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-1-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-1" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="anklesfeet">
      <label for="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-1"> Ankles/Feet</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-2-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-2" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="calves">
      <label for="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-2"> Calves</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-3-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-3" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="diaphragm">
      <label for="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-3"> Diaphragm</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-4-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-4" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="forearms">
      <label for="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-4"> Forearms</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-5-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-5" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="hamstrings">
      <label for="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-5"> Hamstrings</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-6-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-6" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="hip-flexors">
      <label for="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-6"> Hip flexors</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-7-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-7" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="hips">
      <label for="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-7"> Hips</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-8-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-8" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="knees">
      <label for="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-8"> Knees</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-9-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-9" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="lats">
      <label for="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-9"> Lats</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-10-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-10" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="neck">
      <label for="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-10"> Neck</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-11-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-11" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="t-spine">
      <label for="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-11"> T-spine</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-12-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-12" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="target-areas">
      <label for="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-12"> Target Areas</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-13-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-13" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="traps">
      <label for="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-13"> Traps</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-14-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-14" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="triceps">
      <label for="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-14"> Triceps</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-15-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-15" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="upper-body">
      <label for="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-15"> Upper body</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-16-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-16" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="wristshands">
      <label for="div1-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-16"> Wrists/Hands</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkboxes wpas-checkboxes field-container js-wpas-basic-multiple movements">
    <div class="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox--container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="bench-press">
      <label for="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-"> Bench press</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-1-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-1" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="clean">
      <label for="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-1"> Clean</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-2-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-2" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="front-squat">
      <label for="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-2"> Front Squat</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-3-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-3" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="handstand">
      <label for="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-3"> Handstand</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-4-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-4" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="handstand-push-ups">
      <label for="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-4"> Handstand push-ups</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-5-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-5" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="movements">
      <label for="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-5"> Movements</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-6-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-6" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="over-head">
      <label for="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-6"> Over head</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-7-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-7" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="overhead-squat">
      <label for="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-7"> Overhead Squat</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-8-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-8" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="throwing">
      <label for="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-8"> Throwing</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-9-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-9" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="thrusters">
      <label for="div2-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-9"> Thrusters</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkboxes wpas-checkboxes field-container js-wpas-basic-multiple equipments">
    <div class="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox--container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="barbell">
      <label for="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-"> Barbell</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-1-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-1" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="box">
      <label for="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-1"> Box</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-2-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-2" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="dumbbell">
      <label for="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-2"> Dumbbell</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-3-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-3" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="equipment">
      <label for="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-3"> Equipment</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-4-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-4" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="kettle-bell">
      <label for="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-4"> Kettle bell</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-5-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-5" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="long-bands">
      <label for="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-5"> Long bands</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-6-container wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-container wpas-checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-6" class="wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox wpas-checkbox" name="tax_programming-category[]" value="short-bands">
      <label for="div3-wpas-tax_programming-category-checkbox-6"> Short bands</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="Date Added">
  <div class="label-container">
    <label for="order">Sort By</label>
  </div>
  <select id="order" name="order" class="wpas-select orderbyselector">
    <option value="ASC">Oldest First</option>
    <option value="DESC" selected="selected">Newest First</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" class="wpas-submit button" value="Apply Filters">
  <button class="wpas-clear button">Clear Filters</button>
  <input type="hidden" id="wpas-id" name="wpas_id" value="programming-category-filter">
  <input type="hidden" name="wpas_submit" value="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, that works. But I am in a situation that I have no control over the id generation (that lots of work to change the ID).

Comment: Then you're screwed, because that's invalid HTML. The labels are getting associated with the wrong checkboxes.

Comment: I had to change the script which generates the IDs with random value and A single input element and it's label are generating the same ID. So, it's now valid HTML and working.